# Which Tkinter functions should i use to find the coordinates of a randomly placed(in the canvas) text entry and how?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Thanks for looking into my question. I'll try to give you a big and small picture of what I'm trying to do here.

Big Picture:
So, basically I'm trying to make a simple mindmapping program where, after the first entry, every text I input unto the Entry widget is linked to the previous text via a line widget. So like this: Hello----There, and then Hello----There----Yo. Actually, I'm hoping for more modifications in the future like being able to rearrange the links via some metric I have yet explored, but this is basically it.

Small/Specific Picture:
I realize that in order to do this, I will have to find a way to acquire all the xy coordinates of every text drawn on the canvas (text I drew on the canvas by using the random function). I need the coordinates of the first text and the coordinates of the second text so I can use those to draw the line to visually link the two texts. I thought of using an array to list down all inputted text, but I realize that only stores the text and not the location of the text on the canvas. I have explored using tags, or using the coords functions or using the bbox function, but to no avail. Any clues on how to go about this? I would highly appreciate it, Thanks. :)

```
import Tkinter
import random

a = Tkinter.Tk()

b = Tkinter.Canvas(a, width=1000, height=500)
b.pack()

def c(event):
    b.create_text(random.randint(50,940), random.randint(50,480), anchor="center", text=d.get())
    f.append(d.get())
    d.delete(0, 'end')
    print f
    #this function creates a randomly located text taken from the entry widget below and, at the same time, appends the text in the list known as f''

d = Tkinter.Entry(a)
d.pack()
d.bind("<Return>", c)
d.focus()

b.create_line(300, 250, 600, 290)
#this is my very early attempt at linking text inputted and drawn on the Canvas

f = []


a.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does "to no avail" mean? Why didn't using tags and the coords function work? You can use tags to be able to find all objects with the "text" tag, and you can use `coords` to get the coordinates of each object.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use them. ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign random values to variables before you use it to create text on canvas, and keep on list with object ID and text.

```
x = random.randint(...) 
y = random.randint(...) 

obj_id = b.create_text(x, y, ...) 

f.append([x, y, obj_id, d.get()])
```

---

**BTW:** if you have `obj_id` then you can also do

```
x,y = b.coords(obj_id)
```